# Sine wave animation performance advice

Tags: javascript, animation, trigonometry, p5.js

I'm trying to create a sine wave animation in using javascript and have had some success getting the look that I want but I am having performance issues seemingly because of the number of vectors being generated.

I'm currently using the p5js library. Here is a sample of what I have generated so far, would there be any options to optimise this to improve performance whilst keeping the level of detail / smoothness?

```
        function setup () {
            let size = min(windowWidth, windowHeight) * 0.96;
            size = floor(size);
            createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            noiseSeed(random(50));
            frameRate(25); 
            noFill();
        }

        function windowResized () {
            let size = min(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            size = floor(size);
            resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            noiseSeed(random(50));
            frameRate(25); 
            draw();
        }

        function draw () {
            clear();
            beginShape();


            const _o = millis() * 0.0005;
            const amount = 20;
            const ampl = ( 630 / ( windowHeight ) * 100 ) + 120;

            for(var k=0;k<amount;k++) {

                beginShape();

                const offset = (1 - k / amount) * 3;
                const detail = 10;

                for(var i=0;i<(width+detail);i+=detail) {

                    let y = height * 0.5;
                    y += Math.sin(i * 0.01 - _o + ( k / 50 ) + offset) * ampl;
                    y += Math.sin(i * 0.005 - _o + 5 + offset + noise(  50  ) ) * ampl;
                    console.log(i,y);
                    vertex(i, y);

                }
                stroke(255, 255, 255, (k/(amount - 1) * 100));
                frameRate(25); 
                endShape();
            }
        }
```

Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/craiell/pen/zYGbLKm

I am currently using the P5js library but if there are other libraries / methods I am open to alternatives. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be as performant as you can get it to run. The begin/endShape functionality is pretty resource intense, when you are drawing just the line, maybe line() will be a better option?  You'd have to keep previous coordinates. I like the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `console.log` line from inside the nested loops.   This makes the animation smooth on my laptop, even if I increase the frame rate to 60.

I'm not familiar with P5js, but the extra calls to `frameRate()` appear to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas off the top of my head:

1. `for()` loops are blocking the tread, rewrite your code using `foreach()` or `map()` to optimize the flow
2. Check out [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
3. Floating-point operations are expensive. See if you can generate a cache of reusable vector coordinates

Comment: Thank you I'll give those a try.

Comment: p5 uses requestAnimationFrame by default.